# Поиск наиболее часто встречающегося вложенного списка с одинаковыми элементами

Tags: python, list

Есть список с вложенными списками. Нужно найти наиболее часто встречающийся список.

Пример:

> Input:
>
> `[[1,2,3],[2,5,6],[8,2,1],[2,3,1]]`
>
> Output:
>
> `[1,2,3] -> 2 шт`

Списки `[1,2,3]` и `[2,3,1]` cчитаются равными.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Одной строкой (не считая импорта, инициализации `s` и вывода):

```
from collections import Counter
s = [[1,2,3],[2,5,6],[8,2,1],[2,3,1]]
sublist, count = max(Counter(tuple(sorted(x)) for x in s).items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
print('%s -> %d' % (list(sublist), count))
```

Разбор:

1. Превращаем `s` в набор сортированных кортежей (неизменяемых списков, по сути). Сортируем потому, что по условию списки различающиеся только порядком одинаковы, а после сортировки они становятся полностью совпадающими. Преобразование в кортеж нужно потому, что `Counter` из следующего пункта может считать только хешируемые объекты (списки к таким объектам не относятся, а вот кортежи - да): `(tuple(sorted(x)) for x in input)`
2. Отправляем это в `Conter`, получаем объект, в котором подсчитано, сколько каждый объект, в переданном ему "списке" (вообще, итерируемом объекте) встретился: `Counter(...)`. Если на этом этапе вывести полученное значение, будет что-то вроде `Counter({(1, 2, 3): 2, (1, 2, 8): 1, (2, 5, 6): 1})`.
3. Извлекаем из `Counter` пары `(ключ, значение)` (ключ - объект, значение - количество), находим элемент с максимальным значением количества: `max(Counter(...).items(), key=lambda x: x[1])`. Метод `.items()` как раз превращает `Counter` в набор пар (ключ, значение). Параметр `key=lambda x: x[1]` функции `max` говорит, что нужно отбирать максимальное по второму элементу каждой пары.
4. "Распаковываем" полученный элемент (пару подсписок-количество) в переменные `sublist` и `count`: `sublist, count = max(...)`
5. Выводим в виде `"[список] -> количество"`, подсписок показываем в виде списка (а не кортежа): `print('%s -> %d' % (list(sublist), count))`

Вывод:

```
[1, 2, 3] -> 2
```

Ограничения:

1. Изначальный список должен иметь хотя бы один подсписок.
2. При выводе подсписок список всегда будет отсортированным, независимо от того, каким он был в исходном списке.
3. Если в исходном списке несколько подсписков, встречающихся наиболее часто, в результате будет показан только один из них.

Comment: 1- не используйте `input` как переменную — это конфликтует со встроенным именем. 2- Вместо `max()` можно `counter.most_common(1)` использовать: `print(*Counter(tuple(sorted(lst)) for lst in nested).most_common(1)[0])` 3- если повторяющихся элементов внутри вложенных списков нет, то можно `set` использовать: `Counter(map(frozenset, nested))`

Comment: @jfs, 1 - согласен, сейчас поменяю, 2,3 - запомню.

Answer (score 5):

Действия:

- Сортируем подсписки
- подсчитываем их количество
- получаем список и максимальное количество его совпадений

Пример:

```
in_list = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 6], [8, 2, 1], [2, 3, 1]]
print(in_list)

from collections import defaultdict
sub_list_number = defaultdict(int)

# Перебор и подсчет сортированных подсписков
for i in [sorted(i) for i in in_list]:
    # Конвертируем тип на кортеж -- он хэшируемый (только 
    # хэшируемые типы могут быть ключом словаря), в отличии от типа список
    sub_list_number[tuple(i)] += 1

# Сортировка словаря по значению -- количество найденных, подсписков
sub_list_number = sorted(sub_list_number.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])

# Достаем последний элемент -- наиболее часто встреченный список и его количество
max_number_list, number = sub_list_number[-1]
max_number_list = list(max_number_list)
print('{} -> {} шт'.format(max_number_list, number))

# python2:
# print '%s -> %s шт' % (max_number_list, number)
```

Результат:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 6], [8, 2, 1], [2, 3, 1]]
[1, 2, 3] -> 2 шт
```

Answer (score 0):

с Counter конечно наиболее правильный ответ, я привожу просто как еще один вариант подсчета через frozenset

```
lst = [[1,2,3],[2,5,6],[8,2,1],[2,3,1]]
fs = list(map(frozenset, lst))
```

вариант 1

```
dt = {e: fs.count(e) for e in set(fs)}
```

вариант 2

```
import itertools
dt = {}
for a, b in itertools.combinations(fs, 2):
    if a == b:
        try:
            dt[a] += 1
        except KeyError:
            dt[a] = 1
    else:
        dt[a] = 1
```

вывод максимума

```
max_count = max(dt.values())  # 2
max_elements = [e for e in dt if dt[e] == max_count]  # [frozenset({1, 2, 3})]
print([f'{max_count} шт.: {max_elements}'])  # ['2 шт.: [frozenset({1, 2, 3})]']
```